# PySide6 - how do I call objects with dynamically generated string names?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I would like to to generate the "X" in self.X method with concatenating strings.

Obviously, self.text method called below doesn't work.

```
self.myLineEdit_1= QLineEdit(self)

var = 1

text = "myLineEdit_" + str(var) 
        
self.text.setText("text here")
```

I tried to use the self.findChild method as a work around, but that also didn't work.

```
self.myLineEdit_1= QLineEdit(self)

var = 1

text = "myLineEdit_" + str(var) 

child = self.findChild(QLineEdit, text)
child.setText("text here")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't do that. Make a collection of `QLineEdit()` objects and index them by `var`.

Comment: Could you open that up a bit more please?

The thing is that QLineEdit objects are already created with Qt designer, and now I would like to set values to them that I am gathering during a measurement. 
The measurement input gives me the index as well, so I wanted to dynamically create the method name as a string, call the method with that string and assign the measurement value into it.

Comment: @M.Emin are you by any chance trying to do the above by editing a pyuic generated file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have many `QLineEdit()` objects:

```py
self.myLineEdit_1 = QLineEdit(self)
self.myLineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self)
self.myLineEdit_3 = QLineEdit(self)
...
```

then you want them in a collection:

```py
self.lines = [None, self.myLineEdit_1, self.myLineEdit_2, self.myLineEdit_3, ...]
```

Now you can index them:

```py
var = 1    # or how ever you get an index

text = self.lines[var]
        
text.setText("text here")
```

Comment: Ahh that is smart and it absolutely works! 
Thanks very much for the tip @quamrana.